# How do you make an IPv4 address printable with the getdnsapi Python API?

Tags: python, dns, getdnsapi

I'm working with the new [getdns](https://getdnsapi.net/) Python API.

I'm specifically trying to get `DNSSEC_BOGUS` answers. To do this I need to look at the `results.reply_tree.reply[n]['answer']['rdata']['ipv4_address']` elements. This is a 4-byte binary representation of the IPv4 address. Is there an easy way within getdns to change this into a printable IPv4 address?

I don't want to use the `results.just_address_answers` field, because there is no guarantee that the addresses are in the same order.

Here is my sample code:

```
import getdns, sys
def get_ip(hostname, ctx, extensions):
    print("host: {} extensions: {}".format(hostname, extensions))
    results = ctx.address(name=hostname, extensions=extensions)
    print("addresses:")
    for addr in results.just_address_answers:
        print("  {}".format(addr['address_data']))
    print("replies:")
    for reply in results.replies_tree:
        for a in reply['answer']:
            if a['type']==getdns.RRTYPE_A:
                try:
                    print("  type={} data={} dnssec_status={}".format(a['type'], a['rdata']['ipv4_address'], reply['dnssec_status']))
                except KeyError:
                    print("  no dnssec_status")
    print("")

if __name__=="__main__":
    print("getdns.DNSSEC_SECURE={}".format(getdns.DNSSEC_SECURE))
    print("getdns.DNSSEC_INDETERMINATE={}".format(getdns.DNSSEC_INDETERMINATE))
    print("getdns.DNSSEC_INSECURE={}".format(getdns.DNSSEC_INSECURE))
    print("getdns.DNSSEC_BOGUS={}".format(getdns.DNSSEC_BOGUS))
    failed = 'www.dnssec-failed.org'
    ctx = getdns.Context()
    get_ip(failed, ctx, {})
    get_ip(failed, ctx, {'dnssec_return_status' : getdns.EXTENSION_TRUE })
    get_ip(failed, ctx, {"dnssec_return_validation_chain" : getdns.EXTENSION_TRUE})
```

Although this works, I really want the `data=` that prints to print an IPv4 address, not just four binary bytes.

Comment: What kind of data structure is the address in?  Is it 4 bytes as a single 32-bit int?  Or a List, or a `bytes()` object or a struct?

Comment: It appears to be bytes().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bin_addr = results.reply_tree.reply[n]['answer']['rdata']['ipv4_address']
string_addr = '.'.join(map(str, map(ord, bin_addr)))
```

Comment: This works, but I would rather do it within the getdnsapi framework.